# How could/should I handle a RoR 'datetime' "type"/"field"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, time

I am using Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to display date and time in a proper way. That is, I am storing RoR `datetime` (*UTC*) datas and when I output that like `@user.last_sign_in_at` I get `2012-01-14 00:58:18 UTC`. However I would like to output dates and times separately...

Something like `Day: 2012-01-14` and `Time: 00:58:18`.

**How can I "extract" date and time form a RoR `datetime` "type"/"field"? Generally speaking, how could/should I handle those?**

Comment: `datetime` is a MySQL datatype and not ROR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also worth noting are the helpers:

```
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.from_now)       # => 3 minutes
time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 15.hours)      # => about 15 hours
time_ago_in_words(Time.now)                 # => less than a minute
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

Answer (score 3):

You should look into using Ruby's [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) method:

```
@user.last_sign_in_at.strftime("%l:%M%p") # => 9:37AM

@user.last_sign_in_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") # => 01/14/2012
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend the to_formatted_s method of time by adding something like this to your config/initializers:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:verbose] = "%A, %B %d, %Y @ %I:%M %p"
```

This way you don't have to remember the specific formatting strings.  Then in your view:

```
@user.last_sign_in_at.to_formatted_s(:verbose)
```

And here is a link to the [rails defaults](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s).

Comment: Cool!  You can also use `to_s` because it is an alias of `to_formatted_s`.

Answer (score 0):

adding more reference to the answer by @iWasRobbed ::

`@user.last_sign_in_at.strftime` as mentioned above along with other options which can be chosen and looked upon [here](http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/)

You can also check this [gem](https://github.com/radar/dotiw) by Ryan Bigg. There are lots of options here to display time and date in varied formats.

And you can use `some_date.to_s(:db)` to output in the format for your database.